# StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle checking the uniqueness of slug by the two fields

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors for `Translation` and StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle for `Sluggable`. How to make checking the uniqueness of `slug` by the sluggable and locale? I want to get the slug look like this:

```
for EN: /contacts
for PT: /pt/contacts
for PT (if duplicate): /pt/contacts-1
for ES: /es/contacts
```

But now, i have this database [`filter_node_translation`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1w7E.png)

**Entity\FilterNode.php**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="filter_node")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class FilterNode
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

}
```

**FilterNodeTranslation**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="filter_node_translation")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class FilterNodeTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sluggable;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"sluggable"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $slug;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSluggable()
    {
        return $this->sluggable;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $sluggable
     */
    public function setSluggable($sluggable)
    {
        $this->sluggable = $sluggable;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Gedmo sluggable have other configuration option "[unique_base](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#some-other-configuration-options-for-slug-annotation)".

It looks like this:

```
class FilterNodeTranslation
{
   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(updatable=true, unique=true, unique_base="locale", fields={"sluggable"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $slug;
}
```